# TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'load'

Tags: python, sortedcontainers

---

### TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
1 slt = SortedList(load = 1000)
      2 assert slt._load == 10000
      3 assert slt._twice == 20000
      4 assert slt._half == 5000
      5 slt._check()
```

TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'load'

Comment: Why I am Getting Errors On this I referenced this https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/90730/sortedcontainers.SortedListWithKey

Comment: If I got the right docs [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedlist) takes an iterable and optional key, not a "load".

Comment: Oh wait, in the example, its `SortedListWithKey` that has the "load" parameter.

Comment: it still didnt worked

Comment: 22             votes = {}
     23             for _,v in sl:
---> 24                 votes[v] = votes.get(v, 0) + 1
     25             max_votes = 0
     26             max_votes_class = -1

TypeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'

Comment: Please ask a separate question for that

Comment: yes but stackoverflow limit is only 2 questions per day

Answer (score 0):

This is probably coming in a little late but it seems that the load parameter in sortedcontainers has been removed from the later versions. It should still work with version 1.5.7.

https://github.com/mcocdawc/chemcoord/issues/54